# SSRS Matrix - Set Color for Pivot Aggregate

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a relatively simply matrix configured in SSRS. Accounts on the left side and product (well actually product family) on the top. It counts the number of product families represented in an account. Everything works correctly.

Now I want to color code the aggregate (`[Count(productid)]`). I know how to set background color and text color using a function. What I cannot figure out is how to reference the resulting aggregate value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reference the aggregate directly. If you set the textbox properties (color, background color etc) then any calculations/expressions are within the scope of the textbox, unless you specifically state otherwise.

Let's say you wanted a simple colour coded background. You could set the BackgroundColor property of the cell to an expression like this.

```
=SWITCH(
COUNT(Fields!ProductID.Value) >15 , "Red",
COUNT(Fields!ProductID.Value) >10 , "Orange",
COUNT(Fields!ProductID.Value) >5 , "Yellow",
True, Nothing
)
```

As we have not stated the scope, SSRS assumes we mean the scope of the object (the textbox), i.e. the column and row it appears on are taken into account.

The above code on a simple matrix returns something like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the clear and correct answer - worked perfectly! Seems so obvious in retrospect...but then my SSRS is really rusty right now.